# PHP, How to define many properties at once?

Tags: php, oop

I am looking to create a class to pull information from a yahoo data source. Yahoo very nicely provided the following map of data:

http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/enumQuoteProperty

I would like to create a class that will allow me to reference the name of the property and be presented with the code. What is the appropriate way to accomplish this?

I was thinking creating a public function within my data model class and creating an associative array inside of it. Is this best practice? I think I am looking for the PHP equivalent of a C++ struct.

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php (__set, __get) or array

Comment: Yes thank you I am aware of the PHP manual. I've even read it! I'm asking for the best (or even a better/acceptable) way to accomplish a specific task seeing as the people on this site have considerably more PHP experience than I do. I feel like setting 60 constants isn't the best idea. Does using getters/setters make sense as these are external properties not likely to change??

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing you're going to get to a struct is a php object.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

With an object just create some member variables.

If you don't want a ton of member variables, just create one member variable (an array) and use the magic methods __get($k) and __set($k, $v).

```
class foo {
    protected $vars = array();

    public function __get($k) {
        if (isset($this->vars[$k]))
            return $this->vars[$k];
    }

    public function __set($k, $v) {
        return $this->vars[$k] = $v;
    }
}
```

Comment: So for instance, 

class yahoo_properties containing associative array data_dictionary.

$yahooProp = new Yahoo_Properties;
$yahoProp->data_dictionary["Symbol"];

As such? Would my IDE's intelisense be able to parse that associative array the way it would a struct? 

Thanks Ian

Comment: I've never used that IDE so I can't say, but its not likely since the contents of the array are likely to only be set at runtime. PHP is very lazy-loading oriented, so it only executes code when it needs it.  Unless your IDE is very sophisticated, I don't think it'll be able to tell you what keys exists in the array.

Comment: If you really want to know what keys are there, just create a function called `get_keys()` or something and have it return `array_keys($this->vars)`.

Comment: I'd love to find another way to do this. Maybe just a ton of public variables in the class?

Comment: Are the values constant and never change? If so, constants are the way to do it. `class foo { const MOO = 'valueofconstant'; }` which can then be accessed in the class via `self::MOO` and externally via `foo::MOO`.

Answer (score 0):

Class constants are still the better way, in my opinion, regardless the quantity.

```
class MyClass {
    const AfterHoursChangeRealtime = 'c8';
    const AnnualizedGain = 'g3';
    //[...]
}
```

But, if you want avoid declaring a lot of constants or simple make a better access way, you can use an static var with an array.

As static its a class variable and will consume less memory and has faster access, by not copying it's value at every object.

```
class MyClass {
    static $enum = array(
        'AfterHoursChangeRealtime' => 'c8',
        'AnnualizedGain' => 'g3'
    );
    //[...]
}
```

Comment: I guess I misunderstood the question, if the values are supposed to be constant, then yes, ca static array, or constants would be much better. OP mentioned structs, so I thought he was talking about dynamic values.

Comment: SamuraiDio: intelisense cant parse that array for keys though can it?

Comment: By _intelisense_ you mean _autocompletion_, right?
Well, usually IDEs can't autocomplete array indexes, but you may find another solutions. For Aptana Stuio, by example, it's easy to create some code snippets to do the job.

Comment: Usually, the static array is the best solution if you need it's content (indexes and values) in two ways (sometime you have the index and needs the value, others you have the value and needs the index). Otherwise, if you need only the values and just an easier (human readable) access way, constants are still the best approach.